# Error in twilio voice transcription on local machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url, razor, url-routing, twilio

[image]

I am not able to integrate https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/voicemailtranscribe this app in my mvc app.

```
string url = string.Format("{0}makerecording?email={1}", baseUri, Request["email"]);

try



{
    /* Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client */
    var client = new Twilio.TwilioRestClient(sid, token);
    var call = client.InitiateOutboundCall(CallerID, Request["number"], url);

    /* redirect back to the main page with CallSid */
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("index?msg=Calling... {0}&CallSid={1}", Request["number"], call.Sid), false); 
`
```

- I want to record and then want to convert speech to text.
- How to include xml code in cshtml?
- how to call cshtml via its url in InitiaeoutboundCall ?

Is there any sample application in mvc/C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

So the way that Twilio works is when you tell Twilio to start an outbound phone call, you have to give us URL that we can request once the phone call connects. That URL returns the TwiML instructions that you want Twilio to execute during the call. In the voicemail sample, its the MakeRecording endpoint that needs to return the TwiML.

In an MVC application the easiest way to do that is actually just to do it in the controller.  To start, using NuGet install the Twilio.Mvc package.  Once its installed, change the base class of your controller to TwilioController.  Now create a new action method named MakeRecording.  I make one that looks like this:

```
public ActionResult MakeRecording(string email)
{
    var response = new TwilioResponse();
    response.Say("Hello. This is a call from the Twilio voicemail transcription demo.  Please leave a voicemail after the beep, and remember to speak clearly.");
    response.Record(
        new { 
            transcribe=true,
            transcribeCallback=Url.Action("Transcribed", new { email=email}), 
            action=Url.Action("GoodBye"),
            maxLength=30 
        });

    return TwiML(response);
```

You can see I'm using an object named TwilioResponse to generate the TwiML that gets returned to Twilio, in this case telling Twilio to `<Say>` something to the caller, then begin recording the call, transcribe the recording once its complete and then let me know the transcription is done by requesting an endpoint named Transcribed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am interested in expose my local server to be public for twilio to Initiate Outbound Call.

Comment: If you want to expose your local server publicly, we recommend a tool called ngrok, which makes it very easy to do this.  I'd recommend reading: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/10/test-your-webhooks-locally-with-ngrok.html and https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/03/configure-windows-for-local-webhook-testing-using-ngrok.html

Comment: For testing I followed all steps using TwimlBin.com . What I found Transcription was not successful. Why so? Trial accounts are not allowed to do so ?- Thanks